# Changing User-Defined Global Variable Value in ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, expressionengine

Say I've got a global variable which I'm accessing inside a PHP block, which compares to a querystring... if the comparison is true I want to set the value for a global EE variable so that all the other template pages can recognise that the value is not what it normally is - is this possible, or are the global user-defined variables constants?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP [`$GLOBAL` Superglobal Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), for such cases. Say you have written a variable in any block of a particular page as `$a = 123;`.
Now in the same page, but in another block, you can easily change it to something else as `$GLOBALS['a'] = 456;`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer - I actually meant global EE variables though, ones accessed like {this} - if it's not possible I'll go with the purely PHP method of course :)

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, I missed the question point of yours. Thanks for pointing me out. I don't think I know this part of `ExpressionEngine` at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->EE->config->_global_vars['foo'] = 'bar';
```

But keep in mind that the variable may have already been parsed before you have a chance to change it, depending on where and how it's used ([see EE2's parse order discusssion](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/168268/)).